# Store SQL Data within Data Structure/List (Scala)

Tags: sql, list, scala, jdbc, data-structures

I am getting back into programming after many years away and am very rusty with my data structures/lists/etc. especially since I learnt Java and am now working with Scala.

I want to parse a SQL database and store data from this database in some sort of list or data structure in Scala. I have the code to pull data from this database in place and it's working great. I would be populating this list within a loop and then later pulling from this list to do string operations (probably with StringBuilder).

The databases will have tables that have 100k to 1 million rows. I'm getting confused with `immutable` and `mutable` data structures as well as what way would be best to store table name, column name, and row data (three different lists, or three structures with keys?). With `Seq`, `Vector`, `Stream`, `List`, `Array`, `ArrayList`, etc. there seems like a lot of options and I'm not sure what would be best for performance and usability in relation to large data sets.

I've been able to create different types of lists and work a little with them, but I want to know the benefits. Searching for Scala lists/data structures gives me a bunch of junk.

Comment: Look like you tend to reinvent the wheel. There is a lot of flexible Scala tool to work with DB in memory: Slick, Spark, Anorm.

Comment: Thanks! Honestly I was looking for something like that but I had trouble knowing what to search for.